# Web Scraping in R using getURL

Tags: r, web, web-scraping

Hi I am trying to read data of the World's powerfl brands from the link "http://www.forbes.com/powerful-brands/list/3/#tab:rank" into a data fame using R

I am a beginner so I tried using the following code to retrieve the data

```
  library(XML)
  library(RCurl)
  # Read and parse HTML file
  forbe = 'http://www.forbes.com/powerful-brands/list/#tab:rank'

  data <- getURL('http://www.forbes.com/powerful-brands/list/#tab:rank')
  data
  htmldata <- readHTMLTable(data)
  htmldata
```

Could anyone please help me in retrieving data from the webpage mentioned

Answer (score 1):

They use XHR requests to populate the page via javascript. Use browser Developer Tools to see the Network requests

[image]

and grab the JSON directly:

```
brands <- jsonlite::fromJSON("http://www.forbes.com/ajax/list/data?year=2015&uri=powerful-brands&type=organization")
str(brands)

## 'data.frame':    100 obs. of  10 variables:
##  $ position          : int  12 44 83 87 13 22 1 39 16 72 ...
##  $ rank              : int  12 44 83 87 13 22 1 39 16 72 ...
##  $ name              : chr  "AT&T" "Accenture" "Adidas" "Allianz" ...
##  $ uri               : chr  "att" "accenture" "adidas" "allianz" ...
##  $ imageUri          : chr  "att" "accenture" "adidas" "allianz" ...
##  $ industry          : chr  "Telecom" "Business Services" "Apparel" "Financial Services" ...
##  $ revenue           : num  132400 32800 14900 131600 87500 ...
##  $ oneYearValueChange: int  17 14 -14 -6 32 13 17 1 -5 -1 ...
##  $ brandValue        : num  29100 12000 6800 6600 28100 ...
##  $ advertising       : num  3272 88 NA NA 3300 ...
```

Comment: is this the reason when I used getURL or download.file , I was also not reading the data of the whole page ? Also how did you determine that it is a Json data format ?

Comment: Yep. RSelenium and/or phantomjs are other ways besides this. Click on "Preview" to see JSON but also the Content-Type MIME type gives away the fact that it's JSON.

Comment: Is this the only way we can access this data, some one told me to download the whole htmlpage and use htmltreeparse, I could not figure that out, could you please help shed some light on it. I mean how can I access the data differently if I had not known that it was in Json and was being retrieved by some other link.I would really appreciate your help

Comment: As I said. RSelenium (which drives and scrapes an interactive web browser) or a phantomjs script are your other options. You'll need to do some actual research into those technologies. I just recently answered an SO web scraping question demonstrating RSelenium.

Comment: @hrbmstr could you please help in the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34686048/how-to-retrieve-data-from-the-following-html-document-structure-in-r?noredirect=1#comment57119220_34686048

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something like [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/download.file.html). Basically, doing something like:

```
download.file(forbe, htmldata, auto, quiet = FALSE, cacheOK = TRUE)
```

And the read data should be in the htmldata array variable.